# JavaScript execution

Tags: javascript

I have two scripts, which are included in the HTML body.
In the first script I'm initializing a JS-Object which is referenced in the second script tag.

```
<body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://url/script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     obj.a = 1000;
     obj.do();
  </script>
</body>
```

What is happening, if loading time of the first script (via HTTP) is slow?
How is the execution order of the JS in the body?

Comment: See also the [script `async` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script#attr-async).

Comment: @apsillers I don't think that's possible to use here if the inline script is referencing the external script...

Comment: @Ian True enough -- maybe you could cobble together a `load` listener for the external script, but it would be a nightmare for cross-browser compatibility. Otherwise, `async` is only useful if the linked script *is* the primary active script (i.e., not a library) or if the linked script fires a custom event announcing that it is ready, which most libraries don't do.

Comment: @apsillers Exactly, great explanation. That's why I'm weary of using `async` unless I design everything to work that way :)

Answer (score 2):

`<script>` tags within page source are executed synchronously together with the page load.

The browser will not parse or render any HTML after the `<script>` tag until the script finishes downloading and executing.

This is why it's better to move all `<script>` tags to the bottom of the page, so that the HTML is rendered first.

Comment: +1.  Another option is to wrap the second bit of js code in window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... your code here ... });

This way your inline script is executed only after everything's loaded.

Comment: @psema4 That doesn't help at all, since the first JS file still is blocking the HTML being rendered...

Comment: The question was about execution order of JS, not the blocking of HTML rendering.  Using the eventListener ensures that the inline js would run at a specific time. (er, event)

Comment: the problem is, that sometime - for some reasons I cannot explain - the "obj" object which should be initialized in "http://url/script.js" is undefined (without any other errors). So if I get the comments right, this should not be happening, because the script.js is processed before the "obj.a = 1000;" instruction.